FLS Create and Update Vulnerability
if (rec.Agreeto != null) {
  if (
    Schema.sObjectType.Success_Collaboration_Info__c.fields.Agree_Collaborate_with_Success_Run__c.isUpdateable()
  ) {
    phyCollab.Agree_Collaborate_with_Success_Run__c = rec.Agreeto;
  }

  if (
    Schema.sObjectType.Success_Collaboration_Info__c.fields.Collaborating_Status__c.isUpdateable()
  ) {
    if (phyCollab.Agree_to_Collaborate_with_Clinical_Mode__c == 'Yes') {
      phyCollab.Collaborating_Status__c = 'OK to Team';
    } else {
      phyCollab.Collaborating_Status__c = 'Declined';
    }
  }
} else {
  if (rec.CollaboratingStatus != null) {
    phyCollab.Collaborating_Status__c = rec.CollaboratingStatus;
  }
}

This is the code. Here I added isUpdateable for resoling the Issue of FLS Update . but i got Medium FLS Create and FLS Update  Checkmarx issue while running the  Checkmarx security scanner .
In Checkmarx security scanner showing this fileds names
Agree_Collaborate_with_Success_Run__c and Collaborating_Status__c .

Your question is not very clear. We're not an official part of Salesforce here, we can't read your mind, and we can't see your screen or log into your org. You need to [edit] your question to include more details. What is the exact issue you're facing? If you're getting any error messages (from the Apex itself, or from a tool like the Checkmarx security scanner) then you need to include those error messages verbatim (i.e. do not try to shorten or alter them).

You're going to get an flagged in a security scan because the else doesn't check the field's permission first. You just need to rearrange your conditions:
if(Schema.sObjectType.Success_Collaboration_Info__c.fields.Collab_Status__c.isCreatable()) { 
  if(phyCollab.Agree_to_Collaborate_with_Clinical_Mode__c == 'Yes') { 
    team.Collaborating_Status__c = 'OK to Team';
  } else { 
    team.Collaborating_Status__c = 'Declined'; 
  }
}

Note that if a field is able to write on insert, it's also safe to assume it's writable on update, unless the field is a master-detail field.

Thank you so much for your Answer and I edit the question and added more details .
